# Output last row of dataframe with datetime objects?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Total Python novice here, and I'm hoping this is a simple issue, but I have searched far and wide and have not really found anyone else who has encountered this.

I have a dataframe with minute-by-minute data for a period of time encompassing multiple days. I would like to basically do a df.tail(1) on it for each index -- the indexes in this case are simply the dates, although if there is a reason they shouldn't . In other words, I hope to be able to create a new dataframe out of this mass of data that gives me

```
Date           Time          Entry
01/01/2019      15:59          A
01/02/2019      23:59          Z 
01/03/2019      15:59          Q
```

And so forth. It seems like a trivial problem that I should just be able to do in Excel, but with hundreds of days and 1,440 rows per day, it's incredibly unwieldy. I really appreciate anyone who is able to point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You are probably after something like `df.sort_values('Time').groupby('Date').tail(1)` The sort ensures that the latest times are last, and then you group on the Date and pick the last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas doc provides the solution you're looking for:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html

```
df.groupby('Date').tail(1)
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!